# What daf and exact quote is this talking about in the Rashash

Tags: talmud-gemara, commentaries, tannaim, tosfot

BH

The Rashash on the Tosfot daf 7B dibur hamaskil VeIbait Eima brings support from a different Gemara somewhere in Brachot. What’s the exact source and lashon of this? Like where is it? In my Gemara just says נ״א [image]

Comment: could it be page 51?

Comment: Usually we're not fussy about transliteration, but consider checking this out: https://he.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D7%93%22%D7%94